# Network topology information

Tags: objective-c, c, networking, network-programming, topology

I Have a small business network with a couple of switches, end devices but only one router. I want to display the network topology like a graph would like (with the router on top).

I'm only have access to network layer addresses, so I managed to obtain for every device on the network it's ip address and ip network i.e 192.168.2.9 and 192.168.2.0 (mask 255.255.255.0) for every interface that device has.

My guess is that I could analyze the data and build up the network's logical connections. So, What I want to ask is if I'm on the right path to know the network topology (at least for it's  logical connections).

This is all done programmatically (c, and objective-c) and is for a school project.

PLUS: Does anyone know any library that would draw (given this information) the topology?

Comment: Don't know about the network topology and stuff but maybe [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) can provide the drawing abilities you need (see also [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphviz)).

Comment: I don't know how it's implemented, but I know *many* monitoring tools (including OpenNMS) do this (albeit in Java for OpenNMS). Likewise, I know that HP's SAV tool (that comes with HP's Server Automation tool) can do this in conjunction with Network Automation. I presume you've already `nmap` 'd your environment?

Comment: also, this looks like a build-upon your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509876/network-topology

Comment: @warren yes, it is. Any problem that I would make another question out of it?

Comment: no problem, just wanted to make folks aware that you'd asked a previous question on the topic, and this is a follow-on :)

Comment: Ok, It's just that I don't know all the rules for this community. That's why I asked!

Comment: @warren I didn't nmap'd the environment. The project was designed to do it from the ground up. It's all done using c libraries like pcap

Comment: aha - that's cool, too. Never worked with those libs personally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have every device's IP address already, a useful start. From there, a 'manual algorithm' might be:

```
for each ip in devices
  traceroute ip
    for each hop in traceroute
      add hop to graph (if it's not there already)
```

What you're doing is adding each network hop between yourself and the device to a graph structure. If a node (hop) is already found, then you add a new edge. If not, you add an edge and a vertex. The end result will be a graph of every node on the network and the paths taken to reach them - your topology.

So all you've got to do is implement traceroute yourself, build the graph structure to store the results of your traceroute runs and then make something to plot it all nicely! Each of these could generate many questions of their own.

As you've tagged this Objective-C I'll make a leap and assume you're doing this on a Mac. If that is the case, your graphics needs are met nicely with Cocoa's drawing API.

Comment: yeah, I did it both in Linux and Mac, so I can use Cocoa's drawing. The thing is I haven't used cocoa, and don't have much time to learn. So I have to use whatever library is the fastest to learn and have the most documentation

Comment: I don't know the full scope of your project, but if you can get away with @CodeninjaTim's suggestion below then that'd be much, much easier for you (the difficult bit isn't drawing the lines and rectangles, it's figuring out how to lay out the plot which Cocoa won't help you with). Cocoa drawing is pretty straightforward and Apple's tutorials are quite good, but I found this http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/intro_to_quartz/ very helpful as a first intro if you do go that route.

Answer (score 1):

For graphing the easiest approach might be to output a file in dot and then graph it with graphviz.

Comment: Thanks @Codeninja, The final answer would be to do both things, run the pseudo algorithm @Tim proposed and on the way writing a dot file with the network especification.